# Android volley json parsing

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am loading buttons dynamically. At present I have 2 buttons. so when I click on 1st button it loads a new activity. Same activity is loaded for `onclick()` of all the buttons that are dynamically loaded and in that activity data related to that `button` should be displayed. `Onclick()` of the button only particular values from db should be fetched and displayed.

But the `logcat` shows `"NO VALUE FOR LIST".`

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
                        tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                        int flag = 1;
                        for (int i =-1 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++) {
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow(TestDetails.this);
                            tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            if (flag == 1) {
                                TextView b10 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b10.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 30);
                                b10.setText("ID");
                                b10.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                b10.setTop(20);
                                b10.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                b10.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(206, 147, 216));
                                b10.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b10);

                                TextView b6 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b6.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 30);
                                b6.setText("TEST CODE");
                                b6.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                b6.setTop(20);
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                b6.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(206, 147, 216));
                                b6.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b6);

                                TextView b19 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b19.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 30);
                                b19.setTextSize(15);
                                b19.setText("TEST DESCRIPTION");
                                b19.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                b19.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                b19.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(206, 147, 216));
                                tr.addView(b19);

                                TextView b29 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b29.setText("TEST PRICE");
                                b29.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                                b29.setTextColor(Color.rgb(104, 143, 202));
                                b29.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b29);

                                tv.addView(tr);
                                final View vline = new View(TestDetails.this);
                                vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 10));
                                vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                tv.addView(vline);
                                flag = 0;
                            } else {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String n = jsonObject1.getString("test_code");
                                TextView b6 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b6.setText(n);
                                b6.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 30);
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                b6.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                b6.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b6);

                                TextView b1 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b1.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 30);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime1 = jsonObject1.getString("test_description");
                                b1.setText(stime1);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                // b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(186, 104, 200));
                                b1.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                                tr.addView(b1);

                                TextView b2 = new TextView(TestDetails.this);
                                b2.setPadding(10, 30, 110, 30);
                                String stime2 = jsonObject1.getString("test_price");
                                b2.setText(stime2);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(144, 202, 249));
                                b2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b2);

                                tv.addView(tr);
                                final View vline1 = new View(TestDetails.this);
                                vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(1, 132, 143));
                                tv.addView(vline1);
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to display data. Check internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        Log.e("Error", "Failed" +e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to display data. Check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Log.e("Error", "Try Later" +error.toString());

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(TestDetails.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "NO VALUE FOR LIST".

- **Debug** at first. Add **`BREAK-POINT`** on first **`try {`** section
- Check **`JSON RESPONSE`**.
- You should **START**  **`i`** value `0`.

**FYI**

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {

}
```

> The **`init`** step is executed first, and only once. This step allows
>   you to declare and initialize any loop control variables.

```
  for (int i =0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++) 
   {
    ..............
```

Comment: could you elaborate? I dint get u

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar At first, Check JSON response.

Comment: Ok u mean that I start the loop from 0. I will try

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar Check your JSON response. `String response`

Comment: I am new to Android, could you tell how should I do it?

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar No problem. Read https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar Solved this yet?

Comment: nope, I applied the debugger but the value is showing as null

Comment: final String url =  final String url = "https://diagnostic.hisaabwaale.in/AndroidAppController/testGet?franchise_id="+franchise_id; @Intellj Amiya

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar your given LINK perfect. Now debug please. It will clearly tell you why `"NO VALUE FOR LIST"` showing.